# How is computed a ssh (rsa or dsa key) and why it changed?

Tags: ssh, rsa, dsa

In the last week I generated a SSH id_rsa key on my localhost that I have copied in authorized_key file at the right place on the remote server I want to reach without entering password.

This worked fine.

Now this morning trying to log again without password, it seems that the key is now invalid, I am asked for a password.

I have retried to generate a new key, and copy it again on the remote server authorized_key and it now re-works !

My question: Why was the initial key no more valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any way to expire a key (you need a certificate), so I think somebody (ISP) could be override the key for maintenance tasks, or you have override your private key in your local machine. I think the best response is to be sure that your local public key and the remote public key are the same.

Comment: Both key are now different, that why I am looking for the reason why the local machine public key has changed.
When you do a ssh is it always the key from your user .ssh/ that is used ?

Comment: by default yes, but you can specify different keys by hosts. Here is an example http://www.karan.org/blog/index.php/2009/08/25/multiple-ssh-private-keys